# how can i use onchange function on datalist by javascript?

Tags: javascript

I want to get selected datalist attribute value when i change datalist 
my question is total different because i want my code in javascript not in jquery.

```js
function get_data() {
  var sel = document.getElementById("data");
  var get_value_of_selected_datalist = sel.getElementsByTagName("option")[sel.selectedIndex].getAttribute("value");
  alert(get_value_of_selected_datalist);
}
```

```html
<datalist id="data" onchange="get_data()">
    <option value="one">Option 1 Here</option> 
    <option value="two">Option 2 Here</option>
</datalist>
```

Comment: what's error in the code? change your `datalist` to `select`

Comment: i want only datalist

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```js
function get_data(){
  var val = document.getElementById("data1").value;
  alert(val);
}
```

```html
<input id="data1" list="data" onChange="get_data()">
<datalist id="data">
    <option value="one">Option 1 Here</option> 
    <option value="two">Option 2 Here</option>
</datalist>
```

Answer (score 1):

> The `<datalist>` tag specifies a list of pre-defined options for an `<input>` element.

I think you are using `datalist` instead `select` tag

Replace the `datalist` by `select` tag.

```js
get_data = function() {
  var sel = document.getElementById("data");
  var get_value_of_selected_datalist = sel.getElementsByTagName("option")[sel.selectedIndex].getAttribute("value");
  console.log(get_value_of_selected_datalist);
}
```

```html
<select id="data" onchange="get_data()">
  <option value="one">Option 1 Here</option>
  <option value="two">Option 2 Here</option>
</select>
```

---

Or if you want to use `<datalist>` you can use event onchange on the `<input>` tag and check if the value of your input is into the values of datalist.

Like

```js
get_data = function(elem) {
  var options = document.getElementById('data').getElementsByTagName('option');
  var optionVals = [],
    i = 0;

  for (i; i < options.length; i += 1) {
    optionVals.push(options[i].value);
  }

  if (optionVals.indexOf(elem.value) > -1) {
    console.log(elem.value);
  }
}
```

```html
<input list="data" onchange="get_data(this)">
<datalist id="data">
    <option value="one">Option 1 Here</option> 
    <option value="two">Option 2 Here</option>
</datalist>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need an `input` and add the change eventlistener to that input

```js
function get_data(elem) {
  alert(elem.value)
}
```

```html
<input list="data" name="data" onchange='get_data(this)'>
<datalist id="data">
    <option value="one">Option 1 Here</option> 
    <option value="two">Option 2 Here</option>
</datalist>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add input tag in your code apply onchange event in that tag

```
<input list="courses" name="courses" onchange="getData(this)">
```

Check the below code it may helpful

```js
function getData(obj){
alert(obj.value)
}
```

```html
<input list="courses" name="courses" onchange="getData(this)">
<datalist id="courses">
  <option value="Java">
  <option value="JavaScript">
  <option value="Node">
  <option value="Artificial Intelligence">
  <option value="Machine Learning">
</datalist>
```

**Note**: The datalist tag is not supported in Internet Explorer 9 and earlier versions, or in Safari 12.0 and earlier versions.

Answer (score -1):

```js
function get_data(){
var sel = document.getElementById("data");
var get_value_of_selected_datalist = sel.getElementsByTagName("option")[sel.selectedIndex].getAttribute("value");
alert(get_value_of_selected_datalist);
}
```

```html
<select id="data" onchange="get_data()">
    <option value="one">Option 1 Here</option> 
    <option value="two">Option 2 Here</option>
</select>
```

Note:

Point 1: `<select>` element is used to create a drop-down list.

Point 2:  `<option>` tags inside the `<select>` element define the available options in the list

Comment: the question is about datalist

Answer (score -1):

Do something like this, pass event as a parameter to the function. Event will hold the value of HTML from where it is called.

```js
        function get_data(event){
        alert(event.target.value);
        }
```

```html
     <select id="data" onchange="get_data(event)">
            <option value="one">Option 1 Here</option> 
            <option value="two">Option 2 Here</option>
        </select>
```