# how to get value of selected datalist by javascript on change

Tags: javascript, html

I am getting an alert called while refreshing the page but I want to get the value of the datalist by selection of country. can I get value by onchange?

```js
function fun(el) {
  var x = document.getElementById('countrydata').value;
  alert(x)
}
```

```html
<datalist id="countrydata" onchange="fun(this);">
  <option value="Afghanistan">Afghanistan</option>
  <option value="Åland Islands">Åland Islands</option>
  <option value="Albania">Albania</option>
  <option value="India">India</option>
</datalist>
<label for="country">country</label>
<input type="text" list="countrydata" id="country" name="country" size="50" autocomplete="off" />
```

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56290270/16688813).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the onchange="fun(this);" from datalist to input.

```
<datalist id="countrydata">
     <option value="Afghanistan">Afghanistan</option>
     <option value="Åland Islands">Åland Islands</option>
     <option value="Albania">Albania</option>
     <option value="India">India</option>
   </datalist>
<label for="country">country</label>
<input type="text"
  list="countrydata"
  id="country" name="country"
  size="50"
  autocomplete="off"
 onchange="fun(this);" />
<script>
    function fun(el){
        var x = document.getElementById('country').value;
        alert(x)
    }
 </script>
```

Comment: I implemented this but its giving undefiled value

Comment: Edited the answer. Instead of countrydata, we have to get country in fun() function.